# Undefined offset Notice Seems Wrong

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, error-handling, undefined-index

I am surprised and confused.

I have a fully working php web application that is throwing an Undefined offset warning notice and I cannot see why.

I use Codeigniter and have this call to a model:

```
$data = $this->clubinfo_model->get_data($club);
```

An array is returned and print_r confirms that the array is as I expected with the '0' array containing a number of key-value pairs. Here is the print_r output:

Array ( [0] => Array ( [clubID] => 18 [shortname] => Woodmere [fullname] => Woodmere Bridge Club [game1day] => x [DOW] => Thursday [game1time] => [game1location] => [director] => [readdirectory] => [offset] => [urlpath] => [webpage] => ) )

I then make this assignment:

```
$DOW = $data['0']['DOW'];
```

$DOW get the day of week.

Works fine.

But, php reports an error on the assignment line and says:

ERROR - 2015-01-05 05:50:00 --> Severity: Notice  --> Undefined offset: 0 /home3/billhogs/public_html/ccbridgeclub/application/controllers/scores.php 71

Taking out the '0' index gets the expected results--the program does not work.

So, what is going on?

I assume this is unrelated, but the Codeignighter error log reports the Undefined offset warning notice twice.  I have checked and the function with the strange error is only called once anywhere in the project.  Actually, it is only called from an address fed to the default controller.

Bill

Comment: Please show us the output of the array with print_r or var_dump

Comment: Thanks, here is the print_r output:

Array ( [0] => Array ( [clubID] => 18 [shortname] => Woodmere [fullname] => Woodmere Bridge Club [game1day] => x [DOW] => Thursday [game1time] => [game1location] => [director] => [readdirectory] => [offset] => [urlpath] => [webpage] => ) )

Comment: And where is it? Edit the question and add it there

Comment: Yes, it should work, that is why I began my question with I am surprised and confused.

Comment: If `print_r($data);` gives you the output you can access it with: `$data[0]["DOW"]`, otherwise you just make something wrong or you have a stupid mistake in your code which you don't show!

Answer (score 0):

while assigning instead of $data['0']['DOW'] write $data[0]['DOW']

Comment: As i said under the last posted & deleted answer, that doesn't makes a difference, try it out yourself to learn it!

Comment: Thanks, I had tried removing the quotes before and have done so again, and still get the error.  The line now reads:

        $DOW = $data[0]['DOW'];

The above is a cut and paste just to be sure.  The 0 is highlighted in my editor as an unquoted number.